# Python loop port scan script stops without error on port 80

Tags: scripts, python, scanner

I have a python script which scans ports. I scan a host which has 2 open ports (22 and 80).
When my script reach port 22 I get an message with "Open port + running services". 
Then the scripts continues ...
When it reach port 80, it's get stuck. I don't know why, I don't get an error.

Can somebody review my code because I can't find the issue. Thankss

```
    for port in range(1,82):
            s = socket.socket()
            result = s.connect_ex((ip, port))
            s.close()
            if result == 0:
                    s = socket.socket()
                    s.connect((ip, port))
                    data = str(s.recv(1024))
                    s.close()
                    print ("Port {}: Open  --  ".format(port) + (data))
            else:
                    print ("Port {}: Closed".format(port))
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to wait for the connection to timeout when the target host/port isn't open. Sometimes a router or host will quickly return a connection refused, but by default most services are configured to "stealth" and not respond in any way.

You can workaround this problem by using the [setTimeout](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) function in Python on the socket:

```
s.setTimeout(1.0)
```

It accepts a number of seconds, but it can be a floating point number like `0.5` for 500ms.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response but this will skip port 80. And that's not what I want.
I believe it get stuck at this:
data = str(s.recv(1024))
My script expect input he receives but when you connect to port 80, you come in a shell. Do you know how to fix?